# How to update java GUI from Thread?

Tags: java, swing

```
 private void StartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        Queue queue=new Queue();
        int target=Integer.parseInt(Target.getText());
        String path=Path.getText();
        final Producer p=new Producer(queue, target);
        Consumer c=new Consumer(queue);
        p.start();
        c.start();

        while(p.finish !=true)
        {
          Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              ProgressPrecent.setValue(Producer.ProgressPercent);
            }
          };
          if(EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
            r.run();
          }
          else {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
          }
       }
 }
```

I have two classes that have a shared Queue. one of them is Producer that produces till a target other one consume those elements. all of two extends  Thread. I want to display the progress percent to the user, but it freeze my GUI so what should I do?

Comment: try using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable())`

Comment: I did it but it also won't work?

Comment: Well, you will have to be more specific if you need help. You might also want to improve your question to explain your code. Reading the FAQ will help you.

Comment: @sarcan: Not everybody speaks/writes english as their mothertongue. You should not discriminate someone because of language, since it isn't the actual problem. It's about explaining what has been tried etc...

Comment: I had this problem in C# but it solve, you can see the question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141280/updating-progress-bar-from-thread-in-c-sharp

Comment: Several useful examples are cited in the [answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13538275/230513).

Answer (score 6):

I think you will have to put the whole while loop into a thread. Otherwise the loop will block your ActionEvent and thus freezes the UI.

Something like:

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        while(!p.finish){
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
             public void run(){
               ProgressPrecent.setValue(Producer.ProgressPercent);
             }
           }); 
           try{
              Thread.sleep(100);
           }catch(...){}
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: How will you synchronize access to `ProgressPrecent`?

Comment: Just tried to point out that the loop will cause the initial event to block. Updated my answer.

Comment: Without knowing otherwise, it would be dangerous to call `ProgressPrecent.setValue` - All UI updates MUST be executed within the Event Dispatching Thread - While in theory your answer is correct, is misleading and will end in "why do I get paint artifices" questions, followed "but I was told to" answers ...

Answer (score 6):

- `Worker Threads` by default never to invoked `EventDispatchThread`, you have issue with [`Concurency in Swing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- all updates to Swing GUI must be done on EDT
- `Runnable` could be proper way but `ProgressPrecent.setValue(Producer.ProgressPercent);` must be wrapped in `invokeLater`

code

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        ProgressPrecent.setValue(Producer.ProgressPercent);
    }
});
```

- remove testing for EDT,

code lines

```
if(EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
   r.run();
}
```

`Workers Thread` by defaut never ever to invoke EDT, then doesn't matter if is started from EDT, nor tested for `isDispatchThread()` doesn't make me some sence

- never ever, don't to use `Thread.sleep(int`) inside `Swing Listeners`, because caused freeze Swing GUI too
- I think you can to use [SwingWorker for this job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6114890/714968) too