# C# Progressbar value in foreach()

Tags: c#, foreach, progress-bar, progress

I have this code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var max = 0;
        foreach (var address in textBox2.Text.Split(','))
        {
            max = +1;
        }
        var maxp = 100 / max;
        foreach (var address in textBox2.Text.Split(','))
        {
            SendMessage(address);
            progressBar1.Value = +maxp;
        }
    }
```

It calculates how many emails are in the textbox, and then makes a proportion. To each email sent adds the value of progress, the problem is that when I press the button, the progressbar does not move. When all emails are sent the progressbar moves to the end of stroke.
How can I do?

Comment: Using threading and invoking you can archive this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141280/updating-progress-bar-from-thread-in-c-sharp

Comment: If you are using WPF this solution may work for you : http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/08/25/refresh--update-wpf-controls.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your loop and the ui are executing on the same thread. While the loop is busy, it can't update the ui

You can use a `BackgroundWorker` to run the loop on a different thread in the background, then use the BackgroundWorker's `ProgressChanged` event to update your progressbar. You can learn more about BackgroundWorkers [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Again you are executing code on a thread other than the UI thread.  In WinForms you must invoke back to the UI thread and in WPF you must use application dispatcher.

WinForms:

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
    DoSomethingOnUiThread();
});
```

WPF:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>{
  DoSomethingOnUiThread();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You block the UI thread so it cannot refresh the UI until the processing leaves the method.

See three different solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36079335/5114784) with explicitly used threads, `BackgroundWorker` and `async`-`await` techniques.