# C# - BackgroundWorker and ProgressBar, two tasks with single progressbar

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have C# Win Form code with BackgroundWorker and ProgressBar.
Currently the Worker\ProgressBar is running a single setup installation and it works well but now I want the same ProgressBar will serve 2 setup installation,
So ProgressBar till 75% will show progress of first installation and the other 25% for the second one.

I guess I should first set the progressbar maximum value to 50 and when first installation is done update it to 100.
I’m new to C#, what it the best way to do that ? Should I have 2 BackgroundWorker for each installation ? Any example I can use ?

Comment: I recommend to you using `Task.Run` instead of `BackgroundWorker`, read [this post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Progressbar value in foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504541/c-sharp-progressbar-value-in-foreach)

Answer (score -1):

Try like this concept :

```
ProgressBar progessbar = new ProgressBar();

            public void setup1()
            {
                progessbar.Maximum = 100;

                    //**do ur code
                    progessbar.Value = 25;  //25%
                    //**do ur code
                    progessbar.Value = 25;  //50%
                    //**do ur code
                    progessbar.Value = 25;  //75%

            }

            public void setup2()
            {
                    //**do ur code
                    progessbar.Value = 10;  //85%
                    //**do ur code
                    progessbar.Value = 10;  //95%
                    //**do ur code
                    progessbar.Value = 5;  //100%
            }
```